# NHibernate Envers like Audit Log with Entity Framework 6+

Tags: orm, entity-framework-6, audit-logging

NHibernate Envers does a good job of creating an Audit Log whenever an entity is Updated/Deleted.  Basically it creates an Audit table for each auditable entity and write a snapshot of the data into the Audit table.  For e.g. if Customer records are saved in CUSTOMER table then audit log for Customer records will be saved in CUSTOMER_AUD table.

In one of my projects we are using Entity Framework 6.1.  I have searched and looked at various alternatives like [AuditDBContext](http://auditdbcontext.codeplex.com/documentation) and [EntityFramework Extensions](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#audit-log) but none of them provide an out of box solution similar to NHibernate Envers.

I think generating an Audit Log should be a pretty common requirement, so my question is, whether there is any out of box solution for EF 6+ that generates the Audit Log similar to NHibernate Envers?

Comment: Posting the link to [NHibernate Envers](http://envers.bitbucket.org/) as a comment, since it was not letting me do it in the question itself.

Comment: Any EntityFramework experts care to comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom solution using the [AuditDBContext](http://auditdbcontext.codeplex.com/documentation).

Basically, I use the [AuditDBContext](http://auditdbcontext.codeplex.com/documentation) to keep track of what properties have changed and then used that to write information to Audit tables.  The audit tables exactly mirror the main tables with two additional columns:

- REV_TYPE - That indicates the revision type could be Add/Update/Delete
- REV_ID - Indicates a unique revision id for that row.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code? I face a similar requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrackerEnabledDbContext

Its a bit different, but worth taking a look at.

Comment: I tried (and liked) this framework, but for larger databases, the AuditLogDetail table becomes huge. Thus, IMHO, it makes sense to split the audit log on a "per-table" basis.